# Angular 6 Global Enum?

Tags: angular, enums, electron

I have declared an Enum in a component type script file and it's fine and work's well in that component but now i want to use It in another component.

Based on what I read I have try some approaches but with no results.

Where can I declare a global Enum so that I can use it in all my components?

Enum Example :

```
 enum AttendusTypeEnum {
          Todo = 1,
          Sent = 2,
          Corrected = 3
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to create a TS file and export the Enum so that it can be imported by the components that need to use it.

Example of this would be:

`export enum AttendusTypeEnum{
    Todo = 1, Sent = 2, Corrected = 3
};`

Then inside of the component, you would need to 
import { AttendusTypeEnum } from './file location';

here is a link to the stackblitz also: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pud3ri